# JCarrusel Not Working In Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

my site is online for 4 months. and im using jcarrusel on right sidebar for 4 months. but suddenly its not working fine in firefox but in ie and chrome its fine. I dont know the problem? Can u help me? my site is dugunce com

Comment: is your jQuery linked to the latest version? It may break old libraries.

Comment: wow it was easy thank you. ive changed it to 1.8.3 and its fine :) Thank you very much @ShivanRaptor

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments above, change the jQuery version from the latest one to v1.8.3 solved the problem.

Comment: Problem solved for main page but when i clicked one post, on the sidebar its broken again. Ive changed the version 1.8.3 in header why would it happen @ShivanRaptor